Stuck in password loop

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
whiteboyjay ttyi whiteboyjay login: whiteboyjay87

Password:

Login Incorrect

whiteboyjay login: whiteboyjay87

Password:

Welcome to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-31-generic x86_64)

* Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com * Management: https://landscape.canonical.com

* Support: https://ubuntu.com/pro

System Information as of Mon Jul 29 11:06:39 UTC 2024

System load: 0.31 Usage of : 6.4% of 97.6768

Sump usage: ex

Processes: 145 Temperature: 38.8 C

Hemory usage: 2%

Users logged in: e

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

e updates can be applied Immediately.

Enable ESM Apps to receive additional future security updates. See https://ubuntu.com/ess or run: sudo pro status

Falled to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/neta-release-Its. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

whiteboyJay:"s

@whiteboyjay:"s sudo apt-get purge chrome-remote-desktop [sudo] password for whiteboyjay87:

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information... on... Done

E: Unable to locate package chrome-remote-desktop whiteboyjay:"s


Simply posting logvomit that you didn't even read is unlikely to garner helpful responses. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Difficult to determine the issue from what you have posted, but going from the issue title... As a work around have you tried creating a new user with root privileges from a shell terminal?
Also check this Linux Incorrect Password Error Solution | Right Password but still shows Incorrect | Faillock Error

This is more a comment than an answer..
